# How do I set header variables in Javascript when the API names have dashes in them?

Tags: karate

New to Karate.  Rusty at javascript.  I've read through the intuit.karate page.  I'm sending out the S.O.S. here, please be kind.  How would I configure headers via .js when the headers have names like Content-Type?  I am not referring to the value but the actual name.  I have a header api with a mix of names that contain a dash and some that don't.  In addition, can you update a header after a configure but before the actual call.  Trying something like this which is failing miserably:

'''
  Background:

```
* callonce read('getAuthorization.feature')
* configure headers = read('classpath:payload.json')
* print 'headers: ', headers
* configure headers = {"Authorization" : authToken}
```

'''

Where payload.json has static values and Authorization authToken comes from the getAuthorization.feature.  I want the Authorization to be added to the header info from payload.json.

I apologize in advance for any confusion in this question.  I tried the intuit karate page and examples and youtube vids before coming here.

Comment: At this point I am thinking I am just going to have to have * header in every feature file.  The javascript way of making the header dynamic won't work for me due to the dashed in the API Header variable names.  It's a shame because I really like the javascript option. I work for a very large corporation, I would think we are not unique in having dashes in the Header names.

Answer (score 1):

Few changes you can consider

- **When header has a dash in them like `Content-Type`**

```
var header = {}
header["Content-Type"] = "<CONTENT_TYPE>"
```

- **Embedded expression to inject value directly to payload.json when you read**

*payload.json*

```
{
  "Authorization" : "#(authToken)"
  "Content-Type"  : "application/json"
}
```

In the feature file:

```
* callonce read('getAuthorization.feature')
* configure headers = read('classpath:payload.json')
```

above 2 steps should be enough.

- **header using js**

*header.js*

```
function fn() {
    var authCall = karate.callSingle('getAuthorization.feature')
    var headers = {}
    // add all static headers as well
    headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
    headers["Authorization"] = authCall.authToken
    return headers
}
```

In feature:

```
* configure headers = read('classpath:header.js')()
```

or

```
* configure headers = call read('classpath:header.js')
```

Comment: Thank you so very much Babu Sekaran!  I used the second header js function! Only needed to make one tweak. Instead of def authCall... had to change it to var authCall.  Thanks again!!